# TWITTER4J - 404:The URI requested is invalid or the resource requested - code - 34

Tags: java, eclipse, twitter, http-status-code-404, twitter4j

This is my code :

```
   package twitter;

import twitter4j.PagableResponseList;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.User;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

public class getFollowersIds {

public static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "PRIVATE";
public static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "PRIVATE";

public static final String USER_ID = "PRIVATE";

public static final String ACCESS_TOKEN = "PRIVATE";
public static final String ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = "PRIVATE";
public static final int CURSOR = -1;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    twitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);

    AccessToken oathAccessToken = new AccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
    twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(oathAccessToken);

    try {

        PagableResponseList<User> users = twitter.getFriendsList(USER_ID, -1);
        User user = null;

        for (int i = 0 ; i < users.size() ; i++){

            user = users.get(i);
            System.out.println("Following: "+users.size());
            System.out.print("\nID: "+user.getId()+" / User: "+user.getName()+" /");
            System.out.print("\nFollowers: "+user.getFollowersCount()+"\n");
        }

    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

And this is the error lines :

```
Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=7e95ed42 or
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=45f34518
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[7e95ed42-45f34518], statusCode=404, message=Sorry, that page does not exist, code=34, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=RateLimitStatusJSONImpl{remaining=14, limit=15, resetTimeInSeconds=1411644615, secondsUntilReset=710}, version=4.0.2}
    at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:163)
    at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.request(HttpClientBase.java:53)
    at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.get(HttpClientBase.java:71)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.get(TwitterImpl.java:1538)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.getFriendsList(TwitterImpl.java:479)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.getFriendsList(TwitterImpl.java:474)
    at twitter.getFollowersIds.main(getFollowersIds.java:38)
```

Need help pls 
Don't know what happens ...

Error in > PagableResponseList users = twitter.getFriendsList(USER_ID, -1);

Thanks

ThanksthanksthanksthanksthanksThanksthanksthanksthanksthanksThanksthanksthanksthanksthanksThanksthanksthanksthanksthanksThanksthanksthanksthanksthanks

Comment: Which one is your line 38? I'm asking, as you have obviously edited your code before pasting it, and as the line 38 in your snippet is a System.out.println()...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your USER_ID should be a long and not a String. Strings passed to `twitter.getFriendsList()` are for screen names.

More infos here: http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/api/FriendsFollowersResources.html